# TypeError: cancel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'

Tags: python, функции, aiogram

Я все аргументы передал, а все равно выдает ошибку

```
    @dp.message(F.text)
    async def choose_kb(message: Message, state: FSMContext, request: Request, bot: Bot, callback: CallbackQuery):
        try:
            value = main_kb_text[message.text]
        except KeyError:
            await message.answer("Не понял вас!\nвоспользуйтесь кнопками и командой /help")
            return

        match value:
            case 1:
                #await buy_gold(message, bot)
                await selamo.get_buy_gold(message, state, request)
            case 2:
                await selamo.out_gold(message, state, request)
            case 3:
                await rate_kb(message, bot, request)
            case 4:
                await message.answer("Напишите менеджеру @magic779 с хештегом #SELL")
            case 5:
                await selamo.recruit_balance(message, state)
            case 6:
                await profile(message, bot, request)
            case 7:
                await income(message, bot)
            case 8:
                await support(message, bot)
            case 9:
                await cancel(message, state, request, bot, callback)
            case _:
                await message.answer("Не понял вас!\nвоспользуйтесь кнопками и командой /help")
```

cancel()

```
async def cancel(message: Message, state: FSMContext, request: Request, bot: Bot, callback: CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Главное меню:", reply_markup=main_kb)
    print(await state.get_data())
    await state.clear()
    print(await state.get_data())
    print(message.from_user.id)
    await request.gold_freeze(message.from_user.id, 0)
    await callback.answer()
```

error

```
TypeError: cancel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 308, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 157, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\error.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\user_context.py", line 27, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\fsm\middleware.py", line 41, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 120, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python Proj\PET\Telagram SO2 bot\core\middlewares\dbmiddleware.py", line 21, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 42, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 275, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 116, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 111, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 136, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 120, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 42, in call
    return await wrapped()
                 ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cancel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе **полный трейс ошибки**, возможно это поможет лучше понять, в чём проблема на самом деле.

Comment: @CrazyElf отредактировал вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибку.
Дело в том, что была Инлайн и Обычная кнопка и они в при нажатии вызывали одну и ту же функцию
И когда нанимали на обычную кнопку бот не мог ответить на строчку, я просто убрал эту строку

```
await callback.answer()
```